# so that... usage

Tags: modal-verbs, adverbial-phrases, so

> 1) You must carry on so that you **will** succeed
>
> 2)You must carry on so that you **may** succeed
>
> 3)You must carry on so that you **can** succeed

My grammar book is saying that sentence1 is wrong and sentence2  is correct. What about sentence3? Is it correct or wrong? What is the difference in meaning of these three sentences??

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/236140/can-and-could-usage

Comment: @Gustavson Thank You, But what about  first sentence? Is it correct? What is the difference in meaning of the first and second?