# can and could usage

Tags: modal-verbs

what is the difference in meaning of these two sentences???

> You must carry on so that you **can** succeed.
>
> You must carry on so that you **could** succeed.

Answer (score 1):

In purpose clauses with "so that" and "in order that", "can" is used in **present/future** settings, and "could" is used in **past** settings. Thus, you can have:

- You must carry on (now) so that you **can** succeed (in the future).
- You had to carry on (in the past) so that you **could** succeed (in the past).

Depending on the context, instead of "can" you can find "will" or "may", and instead of "could" you can find "would" or "might".

Comment: Does the sentence " You must carry on so that you could succeed" , doesn't mean that, You must carry on so that you may succeed or for a possibility of succeess

Comment: No. Please read my reply.